# To many threads waiting on semaphore

Tags: c#, multithreading, semaphore

Let assume that I have timer calling method every second.

Method is async (must be async) and I sync method by using SemaphoreSlim.
Method require 5 seconds to finish.

I will have many threads waiting on semaphore. Is this true? Is that a problem ?
Since this is timer I will have more and more threads waiting on semaphore.

How can I resolve this issue ?
Is it possible to not wait if semaphore is not released (just skip code)?

Timer:

```
  PoolReportTimer = new Timer(ReportTimerCallback, null, TimeSpan.Zero, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
```

Method:

```
    private static SemaphoreSlim semaphoreSlimValue = new SemaphoreSlim(1, 1);

    private async void ReportTimerCallback(object state)
    {
        try
        {
            await semaphoreSlimValue.WaitAsync();
            await Task.FromResult(0);
            Thread.Sleep(5000);
        }
        finally
        {
            semaphoreSlim.Release();
        }
    }
```

---

EDIT:

I want to get report every few second in async method. But I want be sure that this will not be problem if method need to much time to finish.

---

EDIT 2 - Solution:

```
       private async void ReportTimerCallback(object state)
        {
            if (await semaphoreSlimValue.WaitAsync(10))
            {
                try
                {
                    await Task.FromResult(0);
                    Thread.Sleep(5000);
                }
                finally
                {
                    semaphoreSlim.Release();
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: I don't see the need for the things you have described. This smells like an XY-Problem. Can you describe what you want to *do*? Not code-wise, but what you want to achieve?

Comment: I want get report every few second in async method. But I want be sure that this will not be problem if method need to much time to finish.

Comment: So what if it does take too long? Lets say it takes 2 seconds on a 1 second timer. Do you want to spam new threads until the program dies? And if you *don't* want to wait for one to finish, why the waiting and semaphore?

Comment: I need semaphore because I don't know how to sync in async mehod without semaphore. lock can not be used in async method.

Comment: Can you take a step back from the code. Can you explain what you want to *happen*? So every second you produce a report. What should happen when report generation takes 2 seconds?

Comment: I want second thread to skip semaphore. Something like: if semaphore is not released than do nothing (don't wait). Some other thread will come later when semaphore is released.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to skip waiting for the semaphore if another thread has a hold on it, you can use the [WaitAsync(TimeSpan)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/hh462723(v=vs.110).aspx) method, to pass a timespan (let's say a tenth of a second) and `await` the result. If it's `false`, somebody else is still holding your resource and you can react to that fact (for example by skipping whatever you wanted to do).

Comment: See Edit 2 in my question. Is that what you thought?

Comment: @Raskolnikov Ah, yes.

Comment: Thank you for help.